# Как найти координаты конца отрезка, зная начальную точку, длину отрезка и координаты направления?

Tags: python, математика, геометрия

Имеется начальная точка `[x,y]`, длина отрезка `l` и направляющая `[x1,y1]`.

Как найти координаты конечной точки отрезка `[x2,y2]`?

Comment: С помощью теоремы Пифагора, отношений и правила сложения векторов. Всё это дают в школе.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как вы предлагаете это делать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать направляющий вектор (из условия не совсем понятно, является `направляющая` точкой или вектором )

```
d = end - start
```

Нормировать его (сделать единичной длины, разделив компоненты на длину вектора)

```
ud = d / Length(d)
```

Добавить к начальной точкe произведение `l` и нормированного вектора

```
 p = start + l * ud
```

Comment: Направляющая это точка, которая лежит на этом отрезке.
Можете пожалуйста расписать подробнее? Понятия даже не имею, что такое нормирование...

Comment: А как мы работаем с координатами? т.е., чтобы найти d, нужно (x-x1)+(y-y1)?

Comment: 2D вектор состоит из двух компонентов, каждая координата отдельно dx = x1 - x, dy = y1 - y

Comment: получется, выполняем все эти действия для x'ов, а потом для y'ов?

Comment: Посчитали dx, dy. Нашли длину (это одно число). Поделили dx, dy на длину, получив udx, udy. Посчитали px, py

Comment: В итоге выходит так, что p=end

Comment: так будет, если l (нужная длина) равна длине первого отрезка

Comment: Показывайте код, отредактировав вопрос

Comment: Всё, нашел в чем была моя ошибка, всё работает